# Unmount by UUID?

Tags: uuid, umount

I'm building a script and am able to mount by uuid using `mount -U UUID`, but I can't seem o unmount by uuid.

Is this type of operation possible? How would I do it? `umount` doesn't seem to have this option.

Answer (score 9):

You can try..

```
umount /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID
```

Comment: This is much easier than my (deleted) answer.

Comment: thanks! it works ok